# Update to Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, updates

'Automatic updates' will automatically install the latest software for Windows XP. I need to install XP SP3 update. How can I tell 'Automatic update' utility to tell I need XP SP3 update ? Or should I wait until the PC decide itself :( ?
Its OK if I download the installer file.

Comment: Here's a guide:
[Learn how to install Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/learn-how-to-install-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3)

Comment: Just run Windows Update...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to wait, [you can manually download and install Service Pack 3 from Microsoft.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322389#tosp3)

Comment: "In order to install SP3 manually, you must first have Windows XP Service Pack 1a (SP1a) or Service Pack 2 (SP2) installed"

Comment: @Moab - That's very true, but it's been so long since I've seen a machine that didn't have at least SP2 on it that I'd honestly forgotten about it.  Good to note, despite that

Comment: You never know what old XP install disk they grabbed, bugs me I even remember it, Vista is similar.